# Minify the output of source to as few lines as possible?

Tags: html, apache

Is there a way to combine and remove unnecessary white-space of source outputted from an apache server?

Comment: This question is not a great fit for SO, in general look at http://serverfault.com/ for questions targeted at the sys admin community. Also, please include more detain in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about whitespace. [Compress the output](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip) with [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) and be done.

Comment: It may be easier to approach this by asking where these files come from in the first place? maybe you can prevent the extra white space from ever being there.

Answer (score 0):

I generate static pages that I feed through HTML Tidy.

The command line I use is:

```
tidy -c -n -omit -ashtml -utf8 --doctype strict --drop-proprietary-attributes yes --output-bom no --wrap 0   generated.html > tidy.html
```

It doesn't strip all unnecessary white-space, but it does get rid of most of it. It also eliminates optional tags, which gives a further saving. For the data I'm working with, it shaves 10% off the post-gzip file size.

Obviously, that won't fit your needs by itself, but I have found someone's attempt to produce an [Apache wrapper for Tidy](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=308488). Assuming it works, you can use the options above to generated minimised HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Pretty Diff.  In the following example click the link and the Stack Overflow homepage is minified on request of the tool.

http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify&html&s=https://stackoverflow.com/